# Unable to unwrap data, invalid status CLOSED

Tags: nginx, spring-boot, lets-encrypt, embedded-tomcat-8, vaadin8

Spring-Boot, Vaadin 8 application with vaadin push

```
@Push(transport = Transport.WEBSOCKET_XHR)
```

No problem if the application gets user operation without any pause. Few seconds without any user request/operation get following error on the console. This makes our error log file doodle. 
Thank you in advance.

Spring-boot, vaadin 8, Nginx, Plesk onyx, ubuntu 16, lets-encrypt

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to unwrap data, invalid status [CLOSED]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SecureNioChannel.read(SecureNioChannel.java:604)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1240)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1213)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1186)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.onDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:72)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.doOnDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:171)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.notifyDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:151)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler.upgradeDispatch(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:148)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.UpgradeProcessorInternal.dispatch(UpgradeProcessorInternal.java:54)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:53)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

nginx config:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass https://ip:port;
        proxy_set_header Host             $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Accel-Internal /internal-nginx-static-location;
        access_log off;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

spring boot application.properties

```
server.tomcat.remote_ip_header = x-forwarded-for
server.tomcat.protocol_header = x-forwarded-proto
server.tomcat.port-header = X-Forwarded-Port    
server.use-forward-headers = true
```

in localhost:

```
java.io.EOFException: null
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1250)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1190)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.onDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:72)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.doOnDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:171)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.notifyDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:151)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler.upgradeDispatch(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:148)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.UpgradeProcessorInternal.dispatch(UpgradeProcessorInternal.java:54)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:53)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: You've mentioned in the duplicate issue you've raised on the spring boot tracker that the same app works with Spring Boot 1.5.6. Can you try to trim down a sample that you can share here? There isn't anything spring related in your stack so it's hard for me to find what the problem could be.

Comment: i get following HTTP Status 101 warning exactly same time with the error in our log.
GET /vaadinServlet/PUSH?v-uiId=1&v-pushId=***************&X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0&X-Atmosphere-Framework=2.3.2.vaadin1-javascript&X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket&X-Atmosphere-TrackMessageSize=true&Content-Type=application/json;%20charset=UTF-8&X-atmo-protocol=true HTTP/1.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that was bug by vaadin 8 and fixed in 8.4.1. /atmosphere 2.4.24/